# $G$ acts transitively on a space $X$. If a function on $X$ is $G$-invariant up to measure zero, is it necessarily a constant (up to measure zero)?

Tags: measure-theory, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure, radon-nikodym

Consider a locally compact Hausdorff $σ$-compact topological space $X$ and a locally compact Hausdorff $σ$-compact topological group $G$ acting continuously and transitively on $X$ such that there exists a $G$-invariant Radon measure $\mu$ on $X$.

Now suppose $f: X \to [0, 1]$ is a Borel-measurable function on $X$ that is a.e. $G$-invariant. That means for every $g \in G$ we have$f(g x) = f(x)$ for $\mu$-almost every $x \in X$.

How do you show (if true) that such an $f$ will be constant outside of a set of measure zero?

I'm trying to use this to show that any $G$-invariant measure on $X$ would be unique up to scale using the approach outlined in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3926403/211551).

Comment: No, you are overthinking the problem, you just need to use the assumptions.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you elaborate?

Comment: If you can assume that $X$ is metric, then I have a solution.

Comment: @Yanko I'd be interested in reading it

Comment: @CarlosEsparza You can now.

Answer (score 1):

*This answer assumes that $X$ is metric*.

By assumptions we have:

$$ f(x) = f(gx) \text { } \mu-\text{a.e.} x$$
$$ \Rightarrow \int_X |f(x)-f(gx)|^2 dx=0 $$
$$\Rightarrow \int_G \int_X |f(x)-f(gx)|^2dxdg=0$$
By Fubini (see e.g. [When can a sum and integral be interchanged?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged))
$$\int_X \int_G |f(x)-f(gx)|^2 dg dx=0$$

We therefore deduce that for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ we have for Haar-a.e. $g\in G$ that $f(x) = f(gx)$.

Now a co-null subset(!) must be dense (if the complement contains an open subset it would have positive measure). It is then follows that

Lemma: for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ we have that $f(x)=f(gx)$ for **all** $g\in G$.

The proof uses the fact that the action defined by $G$ on $L^2(X)$ is strongly continuous. It is surely true for a metrix $X$, but I do not know if it is true in the generality you need. See this answer and the paper linked there.
[Ergodic action of dense subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015902/ergodic-action-of-dense-subgroup).

Of course now the proof is complete because for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ we have $f(x) = f(0)$.

Comment: As a minor point you are also assuming that the observable is square integrable.

Comment: @AlpUzman It is bounded and measurable, I think this should be enough to imply square integrability.

Comment: So the whole business where you consider $K ⊆ G$ compact is so that you can apply Fubini's theorem, right? Don't we need a similar argument for $X$? (since $X \times K$ is not guaranteed to be compact)

Comment: I think the proof that $G \curvearrowright L^2(X)$ is stronly continuous only requires approximating $L^2$ functions by compactly supported continuous functions. I think that this should work in any $σ$-compact space.

Comment: The bigger problem seems to be that this requires $f \in L^2(X)$, as @AlpUzman pointed out. I don't think this is minor because it means that the proof only works for finite measure spaces $X$.

Comment: Ok I get it now, but then I do not really use the fact that $f$ is square integrable (if $g$ is zero a.e. then $\int |g|^2 d\mu = 0$ always). Why is Fubini does not work? The space $X$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @CarlosEsparza actually it seems like you are right and $K$ is not needed here at all, you can just integrate over $G$.

Comment: @Yanko, oh right since the integrand is non-negative we don't need any additional hypothese for Fubini's (Tonelli's) theorem.

Comment: @Yanko At some point in your argument you claim that we have a co-null subgroup. The subset in question is co-null, but why is it a subgroup? If it were, then we are done since a co-null subgroup $H$ of $G$ is equal to $G$: Pick $g\in G$, then $gH$ is co-null as well, so $gH\cap H$ is non-empty, so there are $h_1,h_2\in H$ such that $gh_1=h_2$, so $g\in H$.

Comment: Ye it is just a set. If $G$ is polish I could improve it to be a group. Let $X_0$ be a co-null set and let  $A\subseteq G$ be a co-null set so that $f(x)=f(gx)$ for all $g\in A$ and $x\in X_0$. Then,  choose a countable set $a_n\in A$ which is dense in $G$ (here you need that $G$ is separable). Now, $\bigcap_n a_n X_0$ is also co-null and the same goes for all words of elements in $A$. Therefore we can find some $X_1$ co-null and $\{a_n,a_n^{-1}\}$ invariant.  It then follows that $f(x) = f(gx)$ for all $g\in A$ implies $f(x)=f(gx)$ for all $g$ in the group generated by $A$.